# How to access the function's arguments through a function call?

Tags: javascript, function

this program is supposed to stop for 3 sec, log 3000ms have passed, pause for 2, log 2000 ms have passed, etc.

The objective is to write the `callOneByOne` function, and I have it all done I hope except for one tiny thing. I want to get the time duration from the process and put it in the `IwantToPutTheDurationOfEveryCallHere` variable. How can I do that?

```js
'use strict';

function printAfter(waitingTime) {
  return function(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${waitingTime}ms have passed`);
      if (callback) {
        callback();
      }
    }, waitingTime);
  }
}

function callOneByOne($$, $) {
   setTimeout(() => {
      $.call();
      
    }, IwantToPutTheDurationOfEveryCallHere);
}

let processes= [printAfter(3000), printAfter(2000), printAfter(4000)];

(processes.reduce((__, _) => callOneByOne(__, _), _ => _()))();
```

Comment: Please use idiomatic variable names

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: And, typical convention is to use `$` to represent an object provided by a library or framework. When you use it without one (while legal), it further confuses.

Comment: Your processes are not processes.

Comment: @JackBashford Please don't edit out syntax errors from OPs code. Just add a comment that there is one, otherwise you've just potentially fixed the entire problem with no explanation.

Comment: You have a syntax error to work out first... In your `callByOne` function.

Comment: `printAfter()` already waits the specified number of seconds. Why do you need another `setTimeout` in `callByOne()`?

Comment: Otherwise it'll print 2000ms have passed then 3000ms has passed the 4000ms has passed. I want them to print the processes array in order, so before the call, they'll have to wait.

Comment: I'm having trouble working out the whole code, but I think you need to split the timeouts into separate elements of the array, e.g. `[[printAfter, 3000], [printAfter, 2000], [printAfter, 4000]]`.

Comment: Another option is for `printAfter()` to return something like `{func: function(callback) { ...}, timeout: waitingTime}`, and then `callOneByOne` can extract the properties.

Comment: Not allowed in the homework :p

Comment: There won't be any arguments in the array. The functions are called when the array is created, and the return values are stored to the array.

Answer (score 1):

This is a riddle that you are supposed to solve without needing access to the arguments. The returned function from `printCall` already has `waitingTime` in a closure. The trick is to arrange the callbacks in the correct order so they get called in a nested fashion.

Here's one way:

```js
'use strict';

function printCall(waitingTime) {

  return function(callback) {

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${waitingTime}ms have passed`);
      if (callback) {
        callback();
      }
    }, waitingTime);

  }
}

function callOneByOne($$, $) {
  // pretty huh?
  return  _ => $$(() => $(_))
}

let calls = [printCall(3000), printCall(2000), printCall(4000)];

(calls.reduce((__, _) => callOneByOne(__, _), _ => _()))();
```